# How to Handle last record set on BSDDB

Tags: python, bash, berkeley-db

I'm trying to create a script in python to get all data from some db2 db files. I'm able to dump the first file to a CSV file but I'm unable to move to the next files since when reaching to the last record set on that DB file Pyhton complains about not being to get more data but it fails.

```
 row = db.next()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/bsddb/__init__.py", line 314, in next
    rv = _DeadlockWrap(getattr(self.dbc, "next"))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/bsddb/dbutils.py", line 68, in DeadlockWrap
    return function(*_args, **_kwargs)
_bsddb.DBNotFoundError: (-30988, 'DB_NOTFOUND: No matching key/data pair found')


db = bsddb.btopen(PATH)
row = db.first()
while row:
    key = row[0]
    values = row[1].split(",")
    result = '"'+key +'","' + values[51]+'","' + values[22]+'","' + values[66]+'","' + WDATE +'"'
    print result
    row = db.next()
```

I'm not an expert, I've been trying to put pieces together but frustration is killing me. Please help.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you considered adding an exception handler?

Comment: You mention db2 (the RDBMS from IBM), but do you mean the Berkley Db (bdb) instead?   Please fix your question and use the correct tags.

Comment: Hello, I'm not sure how to do the exception handler

Comment: The flags have been modified as recommended. Thank you